# Eclipse, Hibernate 5.0.7 Locked on debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, debugging, tomcat

I have a problem with my web application. This is the context:

- Eclispe 2021-09
- Tomcat 9.0.44
- Java 11.0.12

When I start Eclipse and I run the web application in debug all works perfectly, but when I stop Tomcat and restart immediately the web application, always in debug, it seems locked on HibernateSessionRequestFilter.

This is the `HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java`:

[image: HIbernateSessionRequestFilter.java]
The lock is on line 27:

```
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
```

Analyzing in debug that call, I can see that the application remains locked on the line

```
final Metadata metadata = metadataBuilder.build();
```

of class *Configuration*.

[image]

I noticed that when I stop Tomcat it stop immediately and it throws an error:

```
WARNING: The web application [AlphaPickServer] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.12/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.12/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:553)
 java.base@11.0.12/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
nov 11, 2021 9:53:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
```

Is it possible that Eclipse doesn't stop correctly Tomcat? I tried to stop it using *shutdown.bat* but with no different results. If I close and reopen Eclipse anything changes. If I restart PC, the first time, the debug starts with no problem.

I've noticed that this problem occurr only in debug mode, the run mode works correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like beginning a transaction spins off another thread and makes the caller wait for it to return. Look at your other threads, specifically Timer-0, and if you're really cleaning things up on shutdown like you think you are.

Comment: @nitind where i check the Timer-0, as you said?

Comment: It's another thread in your second screenshot. Select it and hit the Pause button.